# react native jest mock api call custom module

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo

I am new to Jest and just learned React Native Expo. I have a service which handles api calls to a server. I want to test this service by mocking it. I have absolutely no idea why it does not work. The Jest documentation about mocking is quite vague to me.

I don't understand why my original method is not mocked.

My directory looks like the following:

```
services
├── __tests__
|   └──goalService.test.js
|
├── __mocks__
│   └── goalService.tsx
|
└── goalService.tsx
```

The goalService.tsx in the root of the services has methods which returns a promise.

Code from each file:

goalService.tsx in mocks folder

```
// __mocks__/goalService.tsx
class GoalService {

    fakeGoals = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test",
            "description": "test test test",
            "user_id": 2,
            "createdAt": "2020-04-13T11:03:47.231Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-04-13T13:28:58.305Z"
        }
    ];

    GetGoals = (userID) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(this.fakeGoals);
        });
    }

    AddGoal = (newGoal) => {
        this.fakeGoals.push(newGoal);

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(this.fakeGoals);
        })
    }
}
```

goalService.js in tests folder

```
// __tests__/goalService.js
import GoalService from './../goalService';

jest.mock('./../goalService');

it('Fetches goals data', done => {
    return GoalService.GetGoals(2).then(data => {
        expect(data.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
        done();
    });
});
```

goalService.tsx

```
// goalService.tsx
class GoalService {

    url = 'xxx';

    GetGoals = (userID) => {
        return fetch(this.url + 'goal/user/' + userID)
            .then((response) => { 
                return response.json();
            }).then((data) => {
              return data.reverse();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error('Error:', error);
            });
    }

    AddGoal = (newGoal) => {
        return fetch(this.url + 'goal', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(newGoal)
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log('Success:', data);
                return data;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
                return false;
            });
    }
}
...

const goalService = new GoalService();
export default goalService;
```

The test gives the following error:

```
TypeError: _goalService.default.GetGoals is
not a function
```

How exactly do I test GetGoals and AddGoals?

I am really stuck here please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you importing goalService from mocks folder?

Comment: No, I haven't found any examples which imported a file from the mock folder. How should I use it, if I have to import that file?

Comment: there are multiple issues with your code, you are importing "GoalService" in test file, but the file is exporting "goalService". "GoalService" is a class, it doesn't have the function "GetGoals", its prototype has it. when you instantiate that class, the instance can access the function with dot operator. also, you are not even using the mock file in your test. have you checked if you are following the guidelines here:https://www.w3resource.com/jest/es6-class-mocks.php

Comment: also this video has some good explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Fl5GH4eYZ8

Comment: Thank you for the usefull link :). It helped